# Error de CORS - La respuesta no tiene el estado Http OK

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Estoy consumiendo un api en Spring Boot desarrollada por mi con un cliente Angular versión > 11.

Tengo un *HttpInterceptor* que me funciona perfecto al obtener la información del usuario por medio del token enviando a mi SSO pero al llegar al método que consume mi api en SpringBoot me da un error:

> ahas been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

**Angular lógica y error:**

Class Interceptor

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')});
req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer MI-AUTH-TOKEN') });

         });

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log('Evento: ', event);
                }
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

                console.log('Error de HttpInterceptor: ', error);
                return throwError(error);
            }));
    }
}
```

Service que consume las Apis en angular:

```
getListUsers() {
    //==== Esta sollicitud es de preba pero funciona - Es de Keycloak para obtener la info del usuario enviando el token del HttpInterceptor
    this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/tutorial/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo').subscribe({
      next: (response: any) => {
        console.log('Response información usuario por token a keycloak: ', response);
      }, error(response: any) {
        console.log('Error al obtener info de usuario http a Keycloak: ', response);
      }
    });

    // Este da error es un api la cual esta en Spring Boot el error lo dejare debajo
    return this.http.get<Usuario[]>(`${this.url}/list/all`).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Errores:

```
// =========== EL ERROR DE CORS
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/api/users/list/all' from origin 
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass 
access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

// =========== EL ERROR QUE SALE CON HTTPINTERCEPTOR SOLO CON esta linea de código 
>>> this.http.get<Usuario[]>(`${this.url}/list/all

Error de HttpInterceptor:  
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8081/api/users/list/all", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8081/api/users/list/all: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:8081/api/users/list/all"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

**JAVA SPRING BOOT**

Class controller Rest

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/api/users")
@CrossOrigin (origins = "http://localhost:4200",maxAge = 3600)
public class UsuarioController {

@Autowired
IUsuarioService service;

// Lista de usuarios
    @GetMapping (path = "/list/{option}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private ResponseEntity<Object> listUsers(@PathVariable String option) {
        List<UsuarioVO> listusers = service.listUsers(option);
        return ResponseEntity.status(listusers != null ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(listusers != null ? listusers : Util.messageJson("Sin información"));
    }

}
```

Class WebConfig Java:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Intenta colocar en allowed "OPTIONS" tambien

Comment: @zerocool no tampoco funciona agregando el options